# Infinitesimal limit of Poisson process

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, poisson-process

A Poisson process $N_t$ has a jump size $dN$ and a rate $\lambda$. Can a Poisson process be viewed as a diffusion process in the infinitesimal limit, i.e. as $dN \rightarrow 0$? [Here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/24488/does-a-poisson-process-converge-to-an-ito-process-in-long-term) is a related question, but my question is about scaling $dN$ in a finite time frame $t\in [0,T]$ in which case I don't think $\lambda$ would need to go to infinity.

The mean and variance of a Poisson process are both $\lambda$, so I was thinking the diffusion would be
$$dN_t = \lambda dt + \sqrt{\lambda} dB_t.$$

I don't know whether this form holds  or how to prove/disprove it. The Poisson process transition probability is
$$ P(N(t+dt) - N(t) = k) = \frac{(\lambda dt)^k e^{-\lambda dt}}{k!}$$
How can we extend this to the continuous case? Would it be, for $x\in \mathbb{R}$,
$$ P(N(t+dt) - N(t) = x) = \frac{(\lambda dt)^x e^{-\lambda dt}}{\Gamma(x)}?$$

Comment: What is the limit you want to take? For a poisson process $d N_t$ is integer valued, so the limit $d N_t\to 0$ seems strange to me. You can take the limit $d t \to 0$, this gives a Poisson point process, but I think you are already aware of this.

Comment: @ComptonScattering I want to derive a diffusion-like continuous process, similar to how we can derive Brownian motion using sum of Bernoulli trials where the step size $dB = \pm \sqrt{t/n}$, with $n$ being the number of trials in time $t$.

Comment: Isn't this just applying central limit theorem to the number of events in sufficiently long time windows? Or am I missing something still?

Comment: @ComptonScattering Hmm so does this mean the number of events has distribution $\mathcal{N}(\lambda, \lambda)$ as $t\rightarrow \infty$? How could one scale $dN$ so that this applies for finite time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$$
P(N(t+\Delta t)- N(t) = k) = \frac{(\lambda \Delta t)^k \mathrm{e}^{- \lambda \Delta t}}{k !}
$$
as you noted. Over large time intervals $\Delta t$ we thus have a convergence to a normal distribution
$$
\frac{N(t+\Delta t)- N(t) - \lambda \Delta t}{\sqrt{\lambda \Delta t}} \quad \xrightarrow[]{d} \quad \text{Normal}(0,1).
$$
as is standard for a Poisson distribution.

Now consider a random walk
$$
x(t+ d t) = \mu d t + \sigma d W_t 
$$
for which we have
$$
\frac{x(t+\Delta t) - x(t) - \mu \Delta t}{\sigma \sqrt{\Delta t}} \sim \text{Normal(0,1)}
$$
Thus if one restricts to looking stroboscopically at time intervals $t \in \Delta t \mathbb{N}$ we see the two processes exhibit the same convergence in distribution if we set $\sigma = \sqrt{\lambda}$, and $\mu = \lambda$ in the limit of large $\Delta t$.

More coarsely, a Poisson process "looks" like a random walk as long as it is observed on timescales much larger than than the inverse rate constant
$$
\Delta t \gg \lambda^{-1}.
$$

Comment: I'm not totally sure if this answers your question, but it was too long to make as a comment.

Comment: Sorry, I've been trying to figure out the convergence of Poisson to normal -- so my understanding is that: as $\Delta t$ increases, we can apply the CLT since the Poisson process over $\Delta t$ can be viewed as the sum of many independent Poisson processes over smaller time intervals. Then by the CLT, 
$ N(t+ \Delta t) - N(t) \sim \mathcal{N}(\lambda \Delta t , \lambda \Delta t)$ since the definition of Poisson process tells us that the mean and variance of $N(t+ \Delta t) - N(t)$ are both $\lambda \Delta t$, is that right?

Comment: Yes that is the intuition. The only difference above is that I have shifted and rescaled to relate to a standard normal distribution, this shift and rescale is not conceptually important, but is simply to obtain a distribution that is finite in the desired limit of large $\Delta t$.

Comment: Could you explain why $\sigma$ has $\Delta t$ in it? I thought it should be a constant? @ComptonScattering

Comment: Specifically $ \sigma^2 = \lambda \Delta t$

Comment: That was my mistake, I have corrected it.